# Running shell commands with Automator: how to create a droplet launching an "exec" command?

Tags: terminal, automator, bash

I need to create a automator application that launches the following exec command, whenever a image file is dropped onto it (the exec print the image files with some printing params).

```
exec('lpr -o ImageableArea=DS_8x6 -o PageRegion=DS_8x12 -o
PageSize=DS_8x12 -o media=DS_8x12 '.$fullPathOfTheImageFile);
```

How can I create this application? I can't go beyond this point: 
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Run Shell Script action, change **Pass input:**, (upper right hand corner of the *action*), from **to stdin** to **as arguments**. Then you can get the result of the previous action passed to a shell script as an argument. Example:

```
lpr -o ImageableArea=DS_8x6 -o PageRegion=DS_8x12 -o
PageSize=DS_8x12 -o media=DS_8x12 $1
```

[image: Run Shell Script action]